# How to prevent <Image /> from loading a high quality remote image with low a quality in RN 0.59.3

Tags: react-native

I have upgraded my react-native from 0.55.3 to 0.59.3 and on Android high-quality images are showing with low quality.

P.S. using react-native-fast-image v 4.0.14 solves my problem